# Setting a spring property only when its not null

Tags: spring, properties, dependency-injection

Is there a way to set spring property only when its not null ?

```
<bean class="class name">
            <property name="name" value="DependentId"/>
        </bean>
```

I only want to set this property when ID is not null (and it could be null)

I tried this suggested from one of the similar questions but didnt work

```
<bean class="class name">
            <property name="name" value="$(DependentId:#{{null}})"/>
        </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
<bean name="bean name" class="class name">
   <property name="name" value="#{'${dependentId}'=='' ? null : '${dependentId}'}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: is this still going to set the property as empty string if its null? Because the condition says if its empty , set it to null

Comment: Err, indeed - but what do you want to do if the value is null ? The should be another value, what do you expect to be set ?

Comment: I dont want to set the property at all if its returned null from the java file

Comment: As far as I have used Spring, I don't think this is possible. Spring WILL inject the value, whatever may be this value. And if the value is null, it will inject it. - You set another value, but not determine the presence (or not) of the property considering its value.